# Return from unity activity to MainActivity in android studio

Tags: java, c#, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I have made an app in android studio and a game in Unity. Now I want to combint these two together. Starting is no problem in android calling the unityNativePlayer. But when I want to go back from the unity activity to the MainActivity.java it comes to this: I have an exit button in the unity game calling Application.exit(); and nothing happens when I press the button. Is there a mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Application.exit()` does not exist in Unity API.

For the Editor, use `UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false`;

Use `Application.Quit()` for your builds.

It is better to use Editor pre-processor to do this or you will have problem building your code that contains `UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;` line of code for other platforms.

The code below should solved that problem:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
     UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
#else
        Application.Quit();
#endif
```

Please understand that you should **not** have have any exit `UI Button` for mobile devices. It will work but it is a bad design. This is what the physical Home(iOS) or back(Android) buttons are used for.

**EDIT**:

You just want to quit Unity Activity from Java. The function should do it.

```
public void quitUnityActivity ()
{
    UnityPlayer.currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run()
        {
            Log.v("Unity", "Unity Activity Exited!" );
            this.mUnityPlayer.quit();
            UnityPlayer.currentActivity.finish();
        }
    });
}
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
public void quitUnityActivity()
{
    Log.v("Unity", "Unity Activity Exited!");
    this.mUnityPlayer.quit();
    UnityPlayer.currentActivity.finish();
}
```

To call the Java function from Unity using C#.

```
void exitUnity()
{
    AndroidJavaClass myClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.companyName.productName.MyClass");
    myClass.Call("quitUnityActivity");
}
```

Make sure to replace `com.companyName.productName.MyClass` with whatever you named your class in your Android Studio.

Comment: you are right, I can exit now the whole program, but I just want to quit the unitx y activity. Is there also a way to do this?

Comment: @EmanuelGraf I really want to know how you set up this... Your Android app made with Java is loading Unity activity?

Comment: yes it is a big app that hosts the game in it. When the user wants to exit only the game, it should open the Main Activity of the App again.

Comment: @EmanuelGraf I understand what you want to do now. I updated my answer. Read from **EDIT**.

Comment: Very nice! Just a question, how do I start this part of java code if I use a GUI button in unity?

Comment: @EmanuelGraf Modified my answer. If this solved your problem, don't forget to accept it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111931/discussion-between-emanuel-graf-and-programmer).